# how can i enter the values of dynamic input fields into mysql db using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

How can I enter the dynamically created input fields in my database using php?

Code snippet explanation:

Firstly the user enters the date1 and date2 values. The javascript code creates dynamic input fields. Then on submitting the values mysql query executes.
Problem is the mysql query is not able to enter the dynamic values into database.

JS:

```
    function getrates() {

    var date1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById('date1').value);    //taking input from user 
        var date2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById('date2').value);// taking second input from user

        var no_of_days = ((date2-date1) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); //calculating days b/w date1 and date2
         //document.getElementById('nod').value = no_of_days;
        var newDateColumn;
        var newRow;
        var table_columns = 2;

        for(counter = 1; counter<= no_of_days; counter++) {

            newDateColumn = document.createElement("td");
            newDateColumn.innerHTML = "Day "+counter;

            newAmtColumn = document.createElement("td");
            newAmtColumn.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='form-contol'  name='txt"+counter+"'>";
                    newRow = document.createElement("tr");

            newRow.insertBefore(newDateColumn, newRow.appendChild(newAmtColumn));
            //newRow.appendChild(newAmtColumn);


            document.getElementById("ratetab").appendChild(newRow);
        } }
```

HTML:

```
      <label>Date1</label>
      <input  id="date1" name="date1" type="text" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd">
      <label>Date2</label>        
      <input  id="date2" name="date2" type="text" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" onchange="getrates();">


    <table id="ratetab" class="table">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>Rates</th>
             </tr>
                       </table>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
     $conn       = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ratebox', 'root', ''); //db connection
     $date1      = $_POST['date1'];
     $date2      = $_POST['date2'];
     $d1         = new DateTime("$date1");
     $d2         = new DateTime("$date1");
     $no_of_days = $d1->diff($d2)->days; //calculating no of days
     for ($x = 0; $x < $nO_of_days; $x = $x + 1) {
        $rate = $_POST['txt' + counter];
        $conn->query("insert into tb_rate(rates) values (NOW(),'$rate')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
   ?>
```

I am not able to enter the input values into database.

Comment: What in specific is the problem?

Comment: not able to input the values into database

Comment: you are missing a `col` here `$conn->query("insert into tb_rate(rates) values (NOW(),'$rate')")`

Comment: That is not specific at all. You shared three snippets in three different languages. Debug your code so you can tell us where in specific the issue is.

Comment: Thanx @Shehary but i m not getting it..can you send me the replacement snippet

Comment: @Vishnusinghchundawat here `you are missing a col here $conn->query("insert into tb_rate(rates) values (NOW(),'$rate')")` values are datetime and rates but here `(rates) ` you have only one col, don't you think it should be two col, one for datetime and one for rates like `(datetime, rates) `

Comment: yaa @Shehary but then also its not working.

Comment: @Vishnusinghchundawat also in PHP, both posted dates have same variable `$date1`

Comment: a lot doesnt make sense

Comment: agree with @Drew, counter in PHP doesn't make sense, days calculation doesn't make sense, posting this from JS `$_POST['txt' + counter];` doesn't make sense, so many unknowns, and above of all, where is `<form>` to post input values in HTML

Comment: @Vishnusinghchundawat because you don't have `<form>` to post the input values

Comment: upvoting: OP trying to use PDO, and supports his own question with comments. Refreshing !

Answer (score 1):

The below is my 2 cents on the DB only routines. I hope it is useful.

```
<?php
    $date1 = $_POST['date1'];
    $date1 = $_POST['date2'];
    $d1 = new DateTime("$date1");
    $d2 = new DateTime("$date1");
    $no_of_days = $d1->diff($d2)->days; //calculating no of days

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ratebox', 'root', ''); //db connection
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <--- non-production mode, debug

        // figure out what some_column is below in your table
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_rates (some_column,rates) VALUES (now(), :col2)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':col2', $rate);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $nO_of_days; $x = $x + 1) {
            $rate = $_POST['txt'] + counter; // <--- is that better ?
            // problem: $rate still has uncleansed user-supplied data

            // the next line probably has an error. 1 column versus 2 columns in the values():
            //$conn->query("insert into tb_rate(rates) values (NOW(),'$rate')") or die(mysql_error());

            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        // non-production mode, debug
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . ".";
        die();
    }
    // when are you closing that $conn by the way? Something to think about
?>
```

Also **don't** connect with **root** unless in maintenance-mode. Use `prepare` and `bind` with PDO, not passing strings from user-supplied values. What is the point of using PDO otherwise?

So basically, you are combining mysql_* deprecated concepts, error trapping, with PDO, like a cut-and-paste jumble of code. Still allowing for sql-injection imo.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in your mysql query.

```
"insert into tb_rate(rates) values (NOW(),'$rate')"
```

Here you should have two parameter in as table column and you have passed only one. This query should be something like.

```
"insert into tb_rate(date_field, rates) values (NOW(),'$rate')"
```

May this help you.